# CodeIgniter- Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function like this:

```
 function getOptions() {

    $this->db->select('ID, Title');
    $this->db->where('Parent', 0);
    $options = $this->db->get('ItemCategories');
    $options_arr;

    $options_arr['#'] = '-- Please Select Option --';



    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $options_arr[$option]->ID = $option->Title;
    }

    return $options_arr;
}
```

And in `foreach` line there is an error:
**Message: Trying to get property of non-object**

How can i fix it?

Comment: show full error message incuding line where is ana error.

Comment: If `$options_arr` is array, it 1) has no property `ID` 2) cannot have keys which are objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not fetching the result. Add ->result() after get. This will solve your problem.

```
function getOptions() {

    $this->db->select('ID, Title');
    $this->db->where('Parent', 0);
    $options = $this->db->get('ItemCategories')->result();
    $options_arr;

    $options_arr['#'] = '-- Please Select Option --';



    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $options_arr[$option]->ID = $option->Title;
    }

    return $options_arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo here:

```
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $options_arr[$option]->ID = $option->Title;
}
```

should be

```
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $options_arr[$option->ID] = $option->Title;
}
```

And of course consider @HashemQolami answer about `$result = $this->db->result();`.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. But i reliazed that i did a mistake when a wrote my question. Actually my function has the correct syntax as yo said: $options_arr[$option->ID] = $option->Title;  But i have still error